# Changing value of rows that belong to same group and at least one observation in the group meets a condition with dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Let's say I have this dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(Sequence_ID = c(100,100,100,100,101,101,101,101,102,102,102,102,103,103,103,103), Success = c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1))
```

If any one of the rows that have the same Sequence_ID have a 1 in the Success column, then I want all rows in that group to have 1 in the success column.

I can get my desired output with the following code:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  x <- df$Sequence_ID[i]
  if (any(df$success[df$Sequence_ID == x] == 1)){
    df$success[df$Sequence_ID == x] <- 1
  }
}
```

I was wondering if there is a way to do this in dplyr. Thanks in advance

Comment: `ave(df$Success, df$Sequence_ID, FUN = max)` OR `df %>% group_by(Sequence_ID) %>% mutate(S2 = max(Success))`

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Sequence_ID) %>%
  mutate(
    Success = as.integer(any(as.logical(Success)))
  )
```

does the trick :)